No sigue el orden dentro del método .suscribe() en Angular
Necesito saber por qué esta ejecutando primeramente el console.log(payload) y después salta al console.log(final session) en vez de seguir el código en orden.
Entiendo que tiene que ver algo con el suscribe(), pero no estoy logrando saber el por qué.
guardarUsuario(accessToken: string): void {
    let payload = this.obtenerDatosToken(accessToken);
    console.log(payload);

    this.userService.getUsuario(payload.sub).subscribe((usuario) => {
      console.log("value");
      this._usuario = usuario;
      console.log(this._usuario);
    });

    console.log("final session");
    sessionStorage.setItem('usuario', JSON.stringify(this._usuario));
  }

Se ejecuta en este orden en la consola, el error sale debido a que el this._usuario  esta vacío, ya que se asigna después:
0. {objeto payload}

1. final session

2. login.component.ts:37 ERROR SyntaxError: "undefined" is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at get usuario (auth.service.ts:24:28)
    at Object.next (login.component.ts:43:40)
    at ConsumerObserver2.next (Subscriber.js:96:33)
    at Subscriber2._next (Subscriber.js:63:26)
    at Subscriber2.next (Subscriber.js:34:18)
    at map.js:7:24
    at OperatorSubscriber2._this._next (OperatorSubscriber.js:15:21)
    at Subscriber2.next (Subscriber.js:34:18)
    at filter.js:6:143

3. value

4. {objeto this._usuario}


Decir que el método guardarUsuario() se llama en el componente.ts, dentro de otro suscribe(). ¿Puede que este afectando esto también?
login() {
    if (this.usuario.username == null || this.usuario.password == null) {
      swal.fire('Error Login', 'Username o password vacias!', 'error')
      return;
    }

    this.authService.login(this.usuario).subscribe(
      response => {
        this.router.navigate(['/clientes']);

        this.authService.guardarUsuario(response.accessToken);
        this.authService.guardarToken(response.accessToken);
        let usuario = this.authService.usuario;

        swal.fire('Login', `Hola ${usuario.username}, has iniciado sesión con éxito`, 'success');
      }
    );

  }


Tienes un fallo de base importante. Las suscripciones son asíncronas, no se ejecutan en orden lineal... debes guardar el usuario en la callback, no fuera

Vale, muchaas gracias!
